# Is it possible to use custom icons for a custom resourceType in an Azure Managed Application?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-app

Looking at the [schema](https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/viewdefinition/0.0.1-preview/ViewDefinition.json#) I can see some options but nothing that hints at custom icons.  A way to view all compatible icons would also be helpful.  The provided icons in the schema aren't cutting it for me :)

```
"icon": {
  "type": "string",
  "description": "The icon of the view.",
  "x-ms-enum": { "name": "icon", "modelAsString": false },
  "examples": [
    "Add",
    "Delete",
    "Refresh",
    "Go",
    "Stop",
    "Start",
    "Link",
    "Polychromatic.VirtualMachine",
    "Polychromatic.Preview"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible. This is not addressed in any documentation that I can find. I was told during Marketplace publishing the branding logo would automatically replace the Rubik's cube, however this is not the case.